# Buying a house for mother in law

Tags: second-mortgage

I was wondering if anyone could advise me.  I live with my husband, the house that we have purchased is solely in his name and I am not named on the mortgage at all.

His mother is living in a rented property which in a few years is no longer going to be suitable for her to live in.  My wage and savings would be more than enough to buy and pay for a mortgage on a small house for her to live in.  Does the count as a second home or buy to let property? She would not be paying rent and I would be paying the full mortgage.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you edit and add a country tag?

Comment: The answer will vary based on country. If no tag appears soon, we will put the question on hold.

Answer (score 4):

The mortgage company will ask you if the house you are purchasing will be owner occupied.  If it is not, it is considered a second home or investment property.  Since she won't be paying rent, it is just a second home.